# Clean app cache in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing an app based on winPho7 (no updated to 7.5 yet)

In my app, I call to a navigator to show a webpage but my problem is that (still testing)when I deploy the app in the phone, it shows the webpage perfectly.

But if I make changes in the webpage, the next time I open the app, it still shows the older one. My app doesn't get new images, new css, new buttons...

In Android I can delete cache and get the new webpage. How can I do it on winpho?

Now, I have to delete the app, install again and then, it will show the new webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent caching, add a random query parameter to the url, e.g. http://example.com/?ignore=425897425.
That will force retrieving the page again.

I hope that that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks but, I already has a parameter to the url because I have to pass an identification number of the phone. and it still happends.

Comment: Add extra one with `&ignore=random`.